# android java to consume vb.net wcf service

Tags: java, android, vb.net, wcf

How do I get android java to consume a vb.net wcf  service,

this is how it looks in a VB.net Console app to connect to a wcf service. How do I write this in JAVA?

```
    ''http://localhost:9999/Service1.svc
    Dim client As ServiceReference1.Service1Client = New ServiceReference1.Service1Client()
    Dim s As String = client.GetData(2)    
client.Close()
```

---

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private void getServiceNow(){

        //this is how it looks in a VB.net Console app to connect to a wcf service
        //http://localhost:9999/Service1.svc
        //Dim client As ServiceReference1.Service1Client = New ServiceReference1.Service1Client()
        //Dim s As String = client.GetDatas(2)
        //client.Close()
    }



}
```

---

web.config of the wcf service

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

---

```
Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String Implements IService1.GetData


        Return String.Format("You entered: {0}", value)
    End Function

    Public Function GetDataUsingDataContract(ByVal composite As CompositeType) As CompositeType Implements IService1.GetDataUsingDataContract
        If composite Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("composite")
        End If
        If composite.BoolValue Then
            composite.StringValue &= "Suffix"
        End If
        Return composite
    End Function


End Class
```

---

Answer (score 1):

This is not working code but it gives you basic idea how you call service from android.

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9999/Service1.svc/GetDatas");
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/xml");
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(2);
request.setEntity(entity);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

String ss1=EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

I'm not the best java programmer around, but as a proof of concept I was able to write this and connect to my WCF BasicHttpBinding web service (url was Localhost:8085/SyncService/Connect) and upload and download the packages that my web service provices. It's a SOAP service with a DataContract containing class that has only two parameters: a string field and a byte field. The byte field I used for uploading and downloading binaries and into the string field I'd stop a butt load of XML that wrapped up all settings.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import sun.security.util.Debug;

     public class Main {

//constants
final static String WCFNameSpace ="someurl";
final static String DataContractNameSpace ="someurl";
final static String SoapAction ="someurl";


//bare constructor
public Main(){       
}

//structure for sending data back to calling program - mimics the MessageStructure from the host 
public class MsgStruct{
    public String _content;
    public byte[] _bytes;

    public MsgStruct(String s, byte[] bytes){
            _content = s;
            _bytes=bytes;
    }       
}

public MsgStruct CallHost(String URL, String Content, byte[] outBytes){
    String textValue="";
    byte[] inBytes =new byte[] {0};
    try {
        // Creating a new empty SOAP message object
        SOAPMessage reqMsg = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();

        // Populating SOAP body
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = reqMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();                                                    
        SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();                                                                            
        SOAPBodyElement service = body.addBodyElement(envelope.createName("HostConnect", "", WCFNameSpace));                      //good here
        SOAPElement paramInMsg = service.addChildElement(envelope.createName("inMsg", "", ""));                    //good here
        SOAPElement paramBodySection = paramInMsg.addChildElement(envelope.createName("BodySection", "", DataContractNameSpace));   
        SOAPElement paramTextSection = paramInMsg.addChildElement(envelope.createName("TextSection", "", DataContractNameSpace));   

        //get the byte array to send and populate the fields
        String  sOut=org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(outBytes);
        paramBodySection.addTextNode(sOut);  //adding the binary stuff here "AA=="
        paramTextSection.addTextNode(Content); //adding the text content here
        envelope.removeAttribute("Header");
        envelope.setPrefix("s");
        envelope.getBody().setPrefix("s");

        // Setting SOAPAction header line
        MimeHeaders headers = reqMsg.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", SoapAction);                                                                 //good here
        headers.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");                                                                 //good here
        headers.setHeader("Host", "Localhost:8085");                                                                 //good here
        headers.setHeader("Expect", "100-continue");                                                                 

        // Connecting and Calling
        SOAPConnection con = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();
        SOAPMessage resMsg = con.call(reqMsg, URL);
        resMsg.saveChanges();
        con.close();    

        //check the host response
        if (resMsg != null){
            try{
                SOAPBody responseBody = resMsg.getSOAPBody();  
                SOAPBodyElement responseElement0= (SOAPBodyElement)responseBody.getChildElements().next();  
                SOAPElement responseElement1 = (SOAPElement)responseElement0.getChildElements().next();
                SOAPElement bodyElement = (SOAPElement)responseElement1.getFirstChild();
                SOAPElement TextElement = (SOAPElement)responseElement1.getLastChild();
                Node nodeBody = (Node)bodyElement;
                inBytes = getBytesFromDoc(nodeBody);
                textValue = TextElement.getTextContent();
            }catch (SOAPException se){
                    String smessage = se.getMessage();      
            }    
            return new MsgStruct(textValue,inBytes); 
        //no response from host
        }else{
             Debug.println("error","Error- nothign found");
             return null;
        }                
    } catch (Exception e) {
         Debug.println("error",e.getMessage());      
         return null;
    }
}
```

This is probably overkill on the information, but maybe you can pick the parts of this that will work for you.